# Angular 5 - components communication through <router-outlet> not working

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular5

This is driving me crazy, can somebody tell me why I can't communite through components? I'm trying to send a message from HomeComponent to RecipesComponent and vice versa. When I click on testInstruction button, it only logs in the same component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { VoiceInstructionService } from './voice-instruction.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {}
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  template: `<div><button type="button" (click)="testInstruction()">Test Instruction</button></div>`
})
export class HomeComponent {
  instructionSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private voiceInstructionService: VoiceInstructionService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.instructionSubscription = this.voiceInstructionService.instruction$.subscribe(instruction => {
        console.log(instruction);
    }

    testInstruction(): void {
      this.voiceInstructionService.setInstruction('test');
    }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-recipes',
  template: `<div><button type="button" (click)="testInstruction()">Test Instruction</button></div>`
})
export class RecipesComponent {
  instructionSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(private voiceInstructionService: VoiceInstructionService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.instructionSubscription = this.voiceInstructionService.instruction$.subscribe(instruction => {
        console.log(instruction);
    }

    testInstruction(): void {
      this.voiceInstructionService.setInstruction('test');
    }
}
```

voice-instruction.service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class VoiceInstructionService {

  subject = new Subject<string>();
  instruction$ = this.subject.asObservable();

  setInstruction(instruction: string) {
    this.subject.next(instruction);
  }
}
```

app.module:

```
import { routing } from './app.routing';
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent, HomeComponent, RecipesComponent }   from './app.component';
import { VoiceInstructionService } from './voice-instruction.service';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeComponent, RecipesComponent ],
  providers: [ VoiceInstructionService ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

app.routing:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeComponent } from './app.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RecipesComponent } from './app.component';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
   path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'
 },
 {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
     path: 'recipes',
     component: RecipesComponent
  }
]

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

I tried providing the service on the AppComponent as well and it doesn't work.

---

- Angular CLI: 1.5.0
- Node: 7.9.0
- OS: darwin x64
- Angular: 5.2.3

**-- Update**

If I modify app.component to:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() { setTimeout(() => { this.voiceInstructionService.setInstruction('test'); }, 3000); }
}
```

I can see "test" is logged in Home and Recipes components, but it doesn't happen the same if I setInstruction() from Home or Recipe component. Shouldn't this configuration allow me to communicate between siblings?, the service is provided at the highest level.

Comment: It's hard to really tell what might be wrong here. Is it possible to build a plunker or stackblitz that demonstrates the problem? I have an example app here that uses a service to communicate between three different components in an application: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Communication You could compare the techniques there to what you are doing. (The components are in the `product/product-shell` folder

Answer (score 0):

You have routing involved, or rather meaning that both components are not in the view at the same time. A `Subject` requires a `next` to trigger the subscription. So when you call `next` in one component, and the other one is not in view and you navigate to the other component, the subscription will not fire.

What you can use instead, is a `BehaviorSubject`. A `BehaviorSubject` always emits if there is a subscriber. So change `Subject` to a `BehaviorSubject` instead. Also give the `BehaviorSubject` an initial value as it requires one. That should hopefully solve your issue :)

Comment: I also tried with BehaviorSubject and it doesn't work. I have the two routes open in different tabs to test. What else could be?

Comment: Actually if I add ngOnInit() {

    setTimeout(() => { this.voiceInstructionService.setInstruction('test'); }, 3000);

  } to the AppComponent it works. But why cannot be triggered from Home or Recipes components